# Microservices Architecture with System of Records

Tags: architecture, microservices

We are planning to move from Monolith to Microservices architecture. We will not be able to achieve Database per microservice as we have dependency with approximately 50+ System of records.

The objective is to move the logic from Front end channels API server (Mobile API, Website API etc. and put it into microservices which will be horizontally scalable in the Openshift/Kubernetes environment.

1. Is it a feasible plan to move to microservices architecture when we cannot directly connect DB to microservices? Some of the logic will be present in system of records and microservices will be communicating with system of records through REST or MQ.
2. Will it be feasible to talk through message queues or HTTP when talking with system of records though microservices?

The "to be" new architecture is as follows

[image: New Microservices based Architecture]

The Old architecture is as follows.

[image: Old Architecture]

Comment: Looks like all your microservices will share all system of records (+50 databases)? If so, there isn't much benefit in microservices, or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I dont think you are missing anything. Seems like a weird design.

Management is just trying the microservices architecture to combine FE channels logic in one place (in microservices) and use the conternization to scale up.

Comment: All Microservices will not be connected to All system of records.

Comment: To me, it all depends on what microservices you are going to have there and what the eventual goal is. If it's to improve scaling then it again depends on how good you will define the separation of concerns among all services. More "granular" services means more scalability.  In your situation, if services can have multiple purposes and shared databases then there is a high risk that you will still have mostly the same issues with scaling and maintaining as you have now, plus, increased difficulty in understanding of the whole system.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by having microservices that share to the same dataset? Another name for the type of system you describe is a "distributed monolith".

Comment: @cfbd  The Microservice will not share the same dataset but could share database through system of records. Each system of records have many services. Each service from system of records will be its own Microservice (Lower level microservice). The higher level microservice will work by orchestrating the lower level ones. 

Need to know if this design is appropriate or it has flaws.

Comment: @topgun the architecture you describe isn't a microservices architecture. It's called a 'distributed monolith' because your services are interdependent. If you disable one of your lower level services the upper services will come down like a house of cards. A microservice should be the technical authority of a business capability. This includes all data, logic, and behaviours necessary to facilitate that capability.